# Show command as it's being entered in console vim?

Tags: linux, vim, gvim

For example, in gvim if I'm in normal mode then I press "ayiw to yank a word into register a, gvim shows the "ayi as I type it near the bottom right corner. Is it possible to get this real-time display in console vim, if so how?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just add this line to your `.vimrc`:

```
set showcmd
```

From the Vim help:

```
Show (partial) command in the last line of the screen.  Set this
option off if your terminal is slow.
In Visual mode the size of the selected area is shown:
- When selecting characters within a line, the number of characters.
- When selecting more than one line, the number of lines.
- When selecting a block, the size in screen characters:
  {lines}x{columns}.
```